# how to List all CONSTRAINTS of 2 tables at the same time?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm in need of a little bit of help. I know you can view constraints of 1 table at one time using the SQL Command function in the Oracle Apex Application Express 4.0.2.00.07. I want to know How I can modify the command below to view Constraints of my other tables as well within the same command. Is this possible? (e.g `tblOrder, tblProduct`)

```
SELECT constraint_name, 
       constraint_type
  FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
 WHERE table_name = 'tblCustomer';
```

If you can help I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: `SELECT table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE table_name IN ('tblCustomer', 'tblOrder', 'tblProduct')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT constraint_name, constraint_type
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE table_name IN ('tblOrder', 'tblProduct','tblCustomer');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't know why on earth I couldn't think out of the box :P lol probably too much sql is getting to my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can either just use `IN`, listing the tables;

```
SELECT table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS 
WHERE table_name IN ('tblCustomer', 'tblOrder', 'tblProduct')
```

...or since USER_CONSTRAINTS holds just the current user's tables, just plain list all constraints for all tables owned by the user by removing the `WHERE` entirely;

```
SELECT table_name, constraint_name, constraint_type 
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
```

Comment: @user1972594 If either answer helped, you should mark the question as answered and/or upvote the answers to help future visitors. Glad to help :)